# "Електричне коло" та "електричний ланцюг" - абсолютні синоніми?

Tags: переклад, терміни, синоніми, словосполучення

Словник української мови подає значення словосполучення "електричне коло - сукупність тіл або середовищ, які утворюють замкнений шлях для протікання електричного струму". При цьому "Російсько-український словник" подає переклад російського слова "цепь" у галузі електрики як слово "ланцюг". Чим можна вважати словосполучення "електричний ланцюг" вірним і чи є воно повним синонімом до "електричного кола"?

Comment: Статистика Ґуґла: «електричне коло» ~650 знаходжень, «електричний ланцюг» ~8500 знаходжень.

Comment: Пошуку такі речі довіряти не слід - інтернет засмічений автоматично перекладеними текстами, а «електричний ланцюг» є дослівним перекладом російського «Электрическая цепь» - Гугл саме так і перекладає. Вікі має статтю "Електричне коло", мені здається саме цей термін вірний

Answer (score 3):

Часткова відповідь

## Термін «електричне коло» був замінений на термін «електричний ланцюг» у 1948 році

Цитата з третього тому «Лексикографічного бюлетня» 1952 року ([джерело 1](//books.google.com/books?id=-UhNAQAAIAAJ), [джерело 2](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=AnlJAAAAYAAJ)):

> На відміну від попередніх словників, російський термін *электрическая цепь* в „Словнику“ 1948 р. перекладений як *електричний ланцюг*. В словниках двадцятих і тридцятих років цей термін перекладався як *електричне коло*. Настанова упорядників „Словника“ 1948 р. ясна: російський термін *цепь* був правильно перекладений як *ланцюг*. З технічного погляду цей термін також правильніший, ніж *коло*, бо електричний ланцюг практично ніколи не буває схожим на коло, а наближається формою своїх вигинів, петель, розгалужень якраз до ланцюга. Слід зазначити також, що більш природно застосовувати термін „замкнений ланцюг“, ніж „замкнене коло, розімкнене коло“, оскільки коло за його визначенням є тільки замкненою кривою. Поняття „розімкнене коло“ є абсурдним.
>
> Отже, термін електричний ланцюг слід визнати з усіх поглядів обгрунтованим.
>
> З яких же міркувань у попередніх словниках було прийнято термін *електричне коло*? З живої мови його не можна було взяти, оскільки цей термін увійшов в українську мову порівняно недавно. Розв'язання легко знайти, якщо звернутися до іноземних словників. У німецькій мові термін електричний ланцюг має написання „elektrischer Kreis“. Перед авторами словників двадцятих — тридцятих років стояло питання — вибрати правильніший, ближчий до російського термін *електричний ланцюг*, або перекласти з німецького — *електричне коло*. Керуючись „західними“ орієнтаціями, автори вибрали дальший від російського термін *електричне коло*. Здавалося б, що виправлення, прийняте в „Словнику“ 1948 р., мало знайти  широке застосування. У дійсності ж перекладачі до цього часу в мільйонах примірників підручників дають лише термін *електричне коло*. Так само, як і для терміну *ємкість* (і для ряду інших термінів), постає питання — чи варто переучувати школярів, чи не повернутися у дальших виданнях „Словника“ до менш вдалого відповідника *електричне коло*, який при відсутності певного порядку щодо застосування нормативів „Словника“ увійшов у життя шкіл та інститутів. Слід побажати, щоб наступне видання „Словника" щодо технічної термінології було загальнообов'язковим і щоб у випадках незгоди з рекомендаціями „Словника“ зацікавлені установи чи окремі перекладачі були зобов'язані погоджувати свої зауваження та пропозиції з належними інстанціями.

## Однак

«Словник української мови» 1970-х все ще фіксує «електричне коло» (у статті «[коло](http://sum.in.ua/s/kolo)») і не фіксує «електричний ланцюг» (див. статтю «[ланцюг](http://sum.in.ua/s/lancjugh)»).

## Висновки

Не роблю ніяких висновків. Незважаючи на наявність ідеологічного навантаження в тексті «Лексикографічного бюлетня» («західні орієнтації», а там ще в ненаведеному кінці уривку згадуються «геніальні праці товариша Сталіна з питань мовознавства» — але це притаманно для тих років), його міркування щодо доречності слів «коло» і «ланцюг» у цьому випадку я не можу назвати абсолютно безпідставними. З іншого боку, може, те, що геометричне коло після «розмикання» перестає бути колом, навіть краще допоможе терміну «електричне коле» передавати зміст поняття — я не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Більше в жодній мові, окрім російської, електричні мережі не порівнюються з ланцюгом, тому що у цій мові немає слів, які окремо позначають окремо коло і круг.
Сутність значення - є рух електричної енергії по колу від одного одного полюса до іншого. Термін "коло" використовується і в англійській, і в німецькій, і в польській, і в інших європейських мовах.

Answer (score 1):

Як фізик, я не пам'ятаю, щоб ми використовували фразу "електричний ланцюг". Майже завжди це "коло", бо починається там же, де і закінчується (у джерелі струму). Лінійну електричну систему з двома рознесеними потенцілами, напевно, можна назвати і "ланцюгом", бо кола там нема (приміром, коли ви розряджаєте генератор Ван-Граффа у щось заземлене). Але це досить нішеві системи, і на практиці інженери майже завжди працюють саме з колами, тому, як на мене, краще казати саме "коло".

Ну і, відверто кажучи, я не дуже довіряю загальним тлумачним словникам у контексті спеціалізованих технічних термінів. Краще орієнтуватись безпосередньо на мову відповідної спільноти: підручники, статті, лекції, виступи на конференціях, тощо.

Answer (score 0):

Додаток до відповіді @Sasha.

А висновок дуже простий. Ланцюг не зобов'язує з'єднуватися у коло. А коло - є коло. Тобто слово коло є точним для опису суті процесу. А значення ланцюга потребує уточнень, що ланцюг елементів зобов'язаний утворювати коло. Бо джерело електричного кола міститься в одному компоненті кола. Що і замикає ланцюг в коло.

[Електричне коло](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE)  — сукупність сполучених між собою провідниками електронних компонентів, джерел струму й напруги, перемикачів тощо, через яку може проходити електричний струм.

Якщо говорити у дискурсі вказаного визначення, то формування кола є обов'язковим.

Якщо розглядати процес детальніше, то можна виокремити з електричного кола певні ланцюги, послідовності, низки, рядки компонентів тощо для опису потрібних процесів. Будь-яке слово, що описуватиме упорядковану послідовність компонентів по суті буде правильним.

Електричне коло і електричний ланцюг не є повноцінними синонімами. На що вказує також наявність суперечки.

Термін "електричний ланцюг" по суті є правильним, коли не обов'язково вказувати джерело як одне ціле.

Як і завжди у подібних ситуаціях все залежить від дискурсу, від значення, від деталей які хоче передати мовець.